# PostgreSQL: Select text that contains special characters

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-like

I would like to make the selection of the following strings:

```
Pink
Nando's
M&M's
Banana
Black & White
```

As you can see there's a combination of words with and without special characters. The actual list is too long (> 3k items), so I'd like to know the most generic way of making this selection as the following won't work:

```
select *
from my_table
where col1 in (
'Pink',
'Nando's',
'M&M's',
'Banana',
'Black & White')
```

nor will using `LIKE '%my string%'`

Comment: You need to double the `'` in a string literal, otherwise it's interpreted as the end of the string literal. So, `''`, e.g. `'Nando''s'` and `'M&M''s'`

Comment: This requires me editing each relevant string manually. I'm looking for something generic as the actual list I need to input in my query is long (>3k items).

Comment: What you posted is an example of a SQL injection attack. Imagine what would happen if one of the values was `'); DROP TABLE Users;--`. The solution is to use parameters instead of concatenating strings. *No* amount of quoting can prevent these bugs. How was this query constructed and executed? What language are you using? All have a way to use parameterized queries

Comment: How do you obtain that list, and how/why are you executing the query? As Panagiotis says, if you obtain this data from an external source you should not generate a query with those values as a literal as that could make you vulnerable to SQL injection, but instead use a parameterized (aka prepared) statement, and set the values as parameter values.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, this example contains dummy values in order to give an example. The list comes from the same database I want to select these values from - so the names match exactly. I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: In that case use a JOIN or nested query to select the values instead of typing them: `SELECT * from my_table where col1 in (select name from......)`

Comment: This problem - as described in your question - is specific to using string literals in your query. If you have the values already in your database, then you shouldn't generate a statement with literals, but use the values already stored (as suggested by Panagiotis).